# HQL: Is an element of one collection in another collection?

Tags: hibernate, collections, hql

I want to check whether at least one element of a collection (`u.organisations`) is contained in another collection (`?` = excludedOrganisations):

```
select distinct u from SystemUser u
join u.userGroups g 
join u.organisations o
where 3 in elements(g.permissions) and
EACH_ELEMENT_OF(o) not in (?)
```

How can I express the `EACH_ELEMENT_OF` with HQL?

My last trial is:

```
select distinct u from SystemUser u 
join u.userGroups g 
where 3 in elements(g.permissions) and 
not exists (
    select org from Organisation org 
    where org in elements(u.organisations)
    and org not in (?)
)
```

But I get the exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of Organisation.id
```

Comment: Hey, did you made any progress with this?

Comment: My workaround is with a for-loop what is possible with relative few elements.

Comment: Try passing in instead of a list of Organisations, a list with only their ids. I've tried something similar and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a subquery to express it in SQL, therefore subquery is also needed in HQL:

```
select u from SystemUser u 
where not exists (
    select 1 from UserGroup g where g.user = u and g not in (?)
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, maybe because each UserGroup can have multiple users.

Comment: I have also tried `select 1 from UserGroup g where u in elements(g.users) and g not in (?)` in the subselect, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classical example from Hibernate documentation:

```
from Cat as cat
left join cat.kittens as kitten
    with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
```

In your case, this would be:

```
select distinct u from SystemUser u 
join u.userGroups g
join u.organisations o 
where 3 in elements(g.permissions) and 
 o.id not in (?)
```

I'm assuming the Organisation entity has an id field and you can pass in the list of ids.

Comment: The Organisation has an id field. But when I try to execute your query I get: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: And you're passing in as parameter to the query the set of ids, right? Not the set of Organisations..

Comment: It's a set of Organisation objects.

Comment: try passing in only the list of their ids.